# Horizontal posts in Bootstrap

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't seem to find much on this, it may be the way I am wording the question. 
i would like to create a section of content on the home page with columns in it. - let's say 3.

I would like to display the latest three posts of news in these three columns. 
what is the best way to go about this?

Im still a novice with coding, and I don't have a full grasp of php, although I am studying it, so Im struggling as I don't quite know where to start on this one.

I achieved it on a theme I built from the ground up with the help of a tutorial but don't know which bits of php are relevant, I really want to be understanding what I am doing at this point.

Comment: Is it fetching the posts via WordPress you’re having difficulty with, or the actual laying out of the three posts in your template?

Comment: Martin, its the fetching of them, the columns I have no problem creating. - currently dont have the best knowledge of PHP, though have signed up to some online learning and I'm cramming!

Comment: If you’re wanting to get more into PHP, then I highly recommend SitePoint’s resources. It’s how I got my start as a PHP developer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts and the examples on this page. In case you will get something like:

```
<h2>Recent Posts</h2>
<div class="row">
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '3' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<div class="col-sm-4"><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </div> ';
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, its starting to make sense much more now. - I did this once before with a theme i built from scratch, but I followed a tutorial without much understanding. - I can actually see what's happening here. 

Much appreciated!